# Off-page slide panel styles not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css

so i'm trying to create a external Menu Panel, that opens when i click on a button and gets closed when i click again.

The external Panel works fine, but my css isn't working anymore.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var window_height = $(window).height();
  var window_width = $(window).width();

  $('#panel').css('height', window_height - 20);
  $('#wrapper').css('height', window_height - 25).css('width', window_width - 20);
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var value = $('#button').text();

    if (value == 'Menu') {
      $('#wrapper').animate({
        left: 320
      });
      $('#button').text('Close');
    } else {

      $('#wrapper').animate({
        left: 0
      });
      $('#button').text('Menu');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#panel {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(39, 40, 43, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  /*border-right: 2px solid #800000;*/
  margin-top: -5px;
}
#panel img {
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}
#panel ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#panel ul li {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #800000;
  margin-left: -35px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#panel ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #FFF;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
#panel ul li a:hover {
  color: #02832d;
}
#wrapper {
  background: #000;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#button {
  background: #800000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#head {
  max-width: 1200px !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#head img {
  max-width: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#head a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
#head a:hover {
  color: #02832d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="panel">
      <img src="example.png" />
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>


    <div id="wrapper">

      <header id="head">
        <img src="anything.png" />
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#"></a>

      </header>

    </div>

    <button id="button">Menu</button>

    <script src="js/externalPanel.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

So as i said everything that i style outside the external Panel my Css won't change it. For example when i resize my Browser the max-width dosen't work and i don't know why...

Hope someone can help me out.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail? Which element is the max-width not working on? What is the expected result that you are not seeing?

Comment: When i try to resize my Browser the max-width on my wrapper or header isn't working. It resizes but only when i refresh the page it changes my width, otherwise the image or text dosen't move at all. For example i place an image and text on my right side of the Browser window, my Browser window is at 1200px when i resize it to 800px the images or text dosen't move with the Browser, so it's not responisve at all.

Comment: You are modifying the width of the wrapper with JavaScript. I might be misunderstanding, but I think your solution would be to continue using JavaScript to update the wrapper when the window re-sizes. 
$( window ).resize(function() {
  // modify the width of wrapper here.
});

Comment: thanks for your answer :) but i can't get it to work :/ can you help me how i should modify the width of the wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. I think this will solve the issue you are having:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
      $('#panel').css('height', $(window).height() - 20);
      $('#wrapper').css('height', $(window).height() - 25).css('width', $(window).width() - 20);
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) it works now perfectly. great and fast help :)